# Spark: Custom key compare method for reduceByKey

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, key-value, reduce

I needed to use my own class in Scala for the key in the key/value pair. In particular, I have a simple class that holds two variables `id1` and `id2`, and I want the elements to be grouped only based on `id2` and not `id1`. I could not find any information online about how and where you can override the comparison method for the `reduceByKey()` method so that it can group the elements with the same key based on my custom `compare()` method.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can't override the comparison of `reduceByKey` because it would not be able to use the fact that your data is often shuffled by key on separate executors all over your cluster. You can though change the key (and be aware that depending on the transformation/actions that you use this is likely to re-shuffle the data around).

There is a nifty method in RDD to do this called `keyBy`, so you can do something like this:

```
val data: RDD[MyClass] = ...    // Same code you have now.
val byId2 = data.keyBy(_.id2)   //Assuming your ids are Longs, will produce a RDD[(Long,MyClass)]
```

Comment: This should do exactly what you want without any other changes.

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to alter your class, then `reduceByKey` uses `equals` and `hashCode`. So, you can make sure those are defined and that will result in the correct comparisons being used.

Comment: Yes, I am able to. Thank you, I will try to proceed with this.

Comment: Dont forget to upvote and mark as the answer if it works for you :)

Comment: I have come across some other issue which I need to solve before coming back to this, but I will once that is done!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just `map` the `RDD` so that the first element of the pair is the key you want to use?

```
case class MyClass(id1: Int, id2: Int)
val rddToReduce: Rdd[(MyClass, String)] = ... //An RDD with MyClass as key

rddToReduce.map {
  case (MyClass(id1, id2), value) => (id2, (id1, value)) //now the key is id2
} .reduceByKey {
  case (id1, value) => //do the combination here
  ...
} .map {
  case (id2, (id1, combinedValue)) =>
  (MyClass(id1, id2), combinedValue) //rearrange so that MyClass is the key again
}
```

Comment: Something I should have mentioned - after mapping I need the key to stay as my custom Object containing id1 and id2 because even though I need them to be grouped by id2, I need id1 to stay put because I later remap and regroup the values based on id1. I believe what you suggested would throw away id1?

Comment: I've updated the example to pass `id1` through. You're necessarily throwing away some `id1`s though - consider what happens if you have two entries with the same `id2` but different `id1`s? You can only get one element out (because you're combining them since they have the same `id2`), so you'll only get one `id1` out.